# Why does this C++ code to check a credit card based on the Luhn algorithm not work?

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer, luhn

I wrote this code in to check if a credit card number is valid according to the Luhn algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool ccc(string cc) {
  vector<string> digits;
  int aux;
  for (int n = 0; n < cc.length(); ++n) {
    digits.push_back(to_string(cc.at(n)));
    cout << digits[n];
  }
  for (int s = 1; s < digits.size(); s += 2) {
    aux = stoi(digits[s]);
    aux *= 2;
    digits[s] = to_string(aux);
    aux = 0;
    for (int f = 0; f < digits[s].length(); ++f) {
      aux += stoi(to_string(digits[s].at(f)));
    }
    digits[s] = to_string(aux);
    aux = 0;
  }
  for (int b = 0; b < digits.size(); ++b) {
    aux += stoi(digits[b]);
  }
  aux *= 9;
  if (aux % 10 == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  string crecar;
  cout << "CC:\n";
  cin >> crecar;
  if (ccc(crecar)) {
    cout << "Valid\n";
  } else {
    cout << "Invalid\n";
  }
}
```

And I compile with no errors or warnings and I get the following output:

```
CC:
4895045418823857
52565753485253524956565051565355Invalid
```

It should print first every digit of digits, I used that to check what is the program doing internally, but I get that number that is too big. Why is this program failing and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: The first step to fixing a program is to use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, watching values in variables.  Please edit your post with text identifying which statement is causing the issue.  Include variables and their expected values and the actual values.  If you are very nice, you could include a flowchart. :-)

Comment: Unrelated: The converting of characters to strings an then strings to `int`s is excessive. A character that's a digit to its integer value is always `ch - '0'`. You can probably chuck a bunch of code and save a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Consult the `to_string` documentation ([example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)) and you'll see that there is no overload for `char`, but `char` is easily convertible to an `int`, so the `int` overload will be used. Unfortunately you don't get the digit. You get the character's encoded value. So, assuming ascii,  `to_string('4')` won't return a `string` containing 4, it'll return a `string` containing the ascii value of 4: 52.

If you look at the strange number as a stream of 2 digit numbers you'll see you have an ascii representation of your original number.

```
52 56 57 53 48 52 53 52 49 56 56 50 51 56 53 55
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
4  8  9  5  0  4  5  4  1  8  8  2  3  8  5  7
```

The hack fix for this problem is to change

```
digits.push_back(to_string(cc.at(n)));
```

to

```
digits.push_back(string(1,cc.at(n)));
```

construct a `string` that contains 1 copy of the given character and place it in the `vector`

An immediate readability improvement is

```
digits.push_back(cc.substr(n,1));
```

get a sub-string of the current character we're looking at and put it in `digits`.

But all this to `string` to `int` back to `string` is make-work. Just store `int`s and operate on `int`s . If you have digits you can convert digit into an `int` with `digit -'0'` and back again with `digit + '0'`. This will save you and the the computer a lot of effort.

Comment: of course it should really be `vector<char>` since thats what they are then the problem disappears

Comment: @pm100 I think the switch to `int` is still useful because the `digit *= 2` and `digit -= 9` steps get overly complicated with `char`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your code is so long. According to the wikipedia page on the algorithm in question:

```
function checkLuhn(string purportedCC) {
    int nDigits := length(purportedCC)
    int sum := integer(purportedCC[nDigits-1])
    int parity := (nDigits-2) modulus 2
    for i from 0 to nDigits - 2 {
        int digit := integer(purportedCC[i])
        if i modulus 2 = parity
            digit := digit × 2
        if digit > 9
            digit := digit - 9 
        sum := sum + digit
    }
    return (sum modulus 10) = 0
}
```

I don't know what you started with, but yours just seems really weird.